# Manga where the main character goes back in time or respawn after death

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai, time-loop

I'm looking for a manga I read before, but forgot the title. It was about a guy who is finding a way out of a dungeon and when he dies he goes back in time. There's one chapter where he saw a girl who was trapped in the dungeon who committed suicide after he rejected her for her obsessive traits. When he goes back in time again and meets her again, her personality is different.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.   Where and when did you read this?  Can you clarify which one committed suicide?

Comment: hello thank you for the warm welcome. I read about it on mangakakalot 1-2 years ago I had forgot the title because of not frequent update. About the suicide part the MC reject the Girl he rescued from the dungeon due to her obsessive traits when he woke up the next day. He was shocked to see the Girl hangging lifelessly and then the MC went back in time about going for a different route in the dungeon seeing the same girl but somehow her personality is different

Comment: Was this full colour or mostly black & white?

Answer (score 2):

This is *[Dungeon ni Hisomu Yandere na Kanojo ni Ore wa Nando mo Korosareru](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/dungeon-ni-hisomu-yandere-na-kanojo-ni-ore-wa-nando-mo-korosareru)*.

> Kiska is a boy who is mistreated by the villagers. He manages to survive thanks to his childhood friend Namia, who was the only one by his side. One day, Namia is murdered by three men, and Kiska is accused of the crime and **banished to an inescapable class S dungeon**. However, he finds himself in a different world where he can use "**Save and Restart**" to get back on his feet no matter how many times he dies.

The synopsis covers the protagonist being stuck in a dungeon, and the "save and restart" is the time rewind.

The hanging is at the end of chapter 5, after a girl he encounters in the dungeon tries to sleep with him but he declines.

Comment: Thank you this is the one I'm looking for

Comment: @Duane You're welcome. If this is the correct answer, please consider marking it as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer), which you can do by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour).